# How to assign a lead to user using round robin method in MySQL

Tags: mysql

The new lead is generated automatically every 5 mins. I need to assign a `userid` for that lead.

Table name : user

```
|-----|---------------|---------------------|
| uid | name          |         pid         |
|-----|---------------|---------------------|
| 1   |  ram          |          2          |
| 2   |  rani         |          1          |
|-------------------------------------------|
```

Resulting table name : lead

```
|-----|---------------|---------------------|
| id  | lead name     |         uid         |
|-----|---------------|---------------------|
| 1   |  SEC431       |          1          |
| 2   |  SEC432       |          2          |
| 3   |  SEC433       |          1          |
|-------------------------------------------|
```

How to do that?

Comment: I don't understand the question. It's up to your application to determine which `uid` to insert - that's what makes up the logic. Are you asking about how to issue the `INSERT` statement with php?

Comment: no i asking ..how to assign a user id randomly to lead table ..the lead will generate automatically in every 5 minutes i creates a new row and we need to assign a userid to that lead..

Answer (score 1):

If all you're asking is how to select a random user uid from the user table, so that you can use that random id when a lead comes in, you just need to do something like...

```
select uid from user order by rand() limit 1;
```